# VirtualBox - can't connect from host to guest (no need of internet)

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I use VirtualBox `v5.1.2` - host is Windows 10, guest is Linux Debian (6.0.9).
I want to very simple thing which actually doesn't work in my VB: **I only want to connect from host to guest** (where is running database server).
At this moment I have mobile internet connection on host via USB modem but **I don't need internet in guest at all** (either connect to or from guest).

I tried to set on VM network setting: Adapter 1 - > Attached to: Host-only adapter.

In Preferences of VirtualBox: Network -> Host-only  Networks:

Adapter tab ->IPv4 Address: `192.168.150.2`, IPv4 Network Mask: `255.255.255.0`

DHCP Server tab -> Server Address : `192.168.56.100`, Server Mask: `255.255.255.0`, Lower Address Bound: `192.168.56.101`, Upper Address Bound: `192.168.56.254`

After this setting, the result of guest `ifconfig` is:
`eth0 (...) inet addr: 192.168.56.101`
but I can't connect `192.168.56.101` from host: neither ping nor accessing server from host to guest.
Ping result in host is: `Request timed out`.

I was also trying some NAT settings, but also without success.

Firewall is disabled during connection testing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolved :)
Thanks to: https://serverfault.com/questions/131484/cant-access-virtualbox-host-only-network-from-windows-host

The problem was: adapter address was: 192.168.**150**.2, but
addresses range from DHCP: 192.168.**56**.101 - 192.168.**56**.254, so they weren't able to see each other.

After setting adapter address to 192.168.**56**.99 I can connect to the guest service from host :)